# HTTP request with socket.io

Tags: node.js, httprequest, socket.io-client

Is there a way to perform GET and POST requests using only socket.io-client? Regardless of the server framework.

Something like `socket.emit('/endpoint', req)`.

Comment: You can use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API for that

Comment: Can you add more details about you problem and also what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Websocket protocol with HTTP (another protocol). GET and POST are HTTP methods and have nothing to do with Websockets.

The only similarity between Websocket and HTTP is, that both are using TCP on the layer below.